# jQuery Toggle not working on local and on my website but working on jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have developed a small script where you click a button and a paragraph is displayed using the ".toggle" selector in jQuery. However my code only works on jsFiddle but not on my local drive or on my website?

My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").hide();
});

$(".hide-button").click(function () {
    $("p.main-paragraph").toggle(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
    Content Title
</h2>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat. <a href="#" class="hide-button">Read more/less</a>
</p>
<div class="main-paragraph">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tgrfqrn0/)

[Website](http://brunelstudents.com/volunteering/) (you will see "read more/less" hyperlink.

Thank you!

Comment: `JSFIddle` executes scripts on `onLoad` event by default. Which will do event binding once all the DOM(and all the resources) is ready..

Comment: Your `click` handler is outside the `document.ready` handler - put it *inside*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your `click()` event **inside** the `ready()` function. (As @Rory McCrossan said also)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").hide();

    $(".hide-button").click(function () {
      $(".main-paragraph").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you! so much!! I can't upvote because I need 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing the `.main-paragraph`. Use `slideToggle` for the same. Also the class `main-paragraph` is a `div` and not `p`. So, basically your code was not executing because of that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").hide();
});

$(".hide-button").click(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").slideToggle(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Content Title
  </h2>

  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat. <a href="#" class="hide-button">Read more/less</a>
  </p>
  <div class="main-paragraph">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because in the jsFiddle correct code is written already. Please check

Comment: `SO-snippets` do include `script` as last child of `body`

Comment: No, until you include them. I have provided `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to include jQuery

Comment: For me, Issue is quiet straight forward, Events are being attached when element is not there in the `DOM`

Comment: You must have in in `$(document).ready`.. I do not find it anywhere in your answer!

Comment: It is there. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Include your click handler within your `$(document).ready(function(){})` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").hide();
  $(".hide-button").click(function () {
    $("p.main-paragraph").toggle(500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-paragraph").hide();
});


$(".hide-button").click(function () {

    $(".main-paragraph").slideToggle(500);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>
    Content Title
</h2>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat. <a href="#" class="hide-button">Read more/less</a>
</p>
<div class="main-paragraph">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis felis egestas tortor consequat aliquam id a nisl. Integer nisi tortor, luctus eget erat ac, lacinia tincidunt odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent non facilisis lectus. Aliquam pretium placerat elit. Vestibulum fermentum diam in magna placerat lobortis. Aliquam eu nisl ultrices, consectetur dolor eu, malesuada erat.</p>
</div>
```